# Javascript init function breaks because of this keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues writing my JavaScript/Jquery correctly because I'm a newbie. I have a couple of functions that are breaking each other because of the `this` keyword. All of the functions that are breaking are listed below and the last one is what causes me to know that it is the `this` keyword:

```
// Functions that break
var gp;

gp = function() {
  var autocomplete, input, types;
  input = document.getElementById('loc-input');
  types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', gp);

$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent('.navbar-nav li').addClass('active');

$('ul.nav li.dropdown, .dropdown-hover').hover((function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeIn();
}), function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut();
});

$('.form-control').mousedown(function() {
  if (!$(this).is(':focus')) {
    return;
  }
  $(this).blur().focus();
});

$('#new_item').dropzone({
  acceptedFiles: '.jpeg, .jpg, .png',
  // Area that causes functions to break
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone;
    myDropzone = this;
    this.element.querySelector('button[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
    this.on('sendingmultiple', function() {});
    this.on('successmultiple', function(files, response) {});
    this.on('errormultiple', function(files, response) {});
  }
});
```

This area right here (inner function) if commented out makes all the JavaScript work again but if used, all is lost:

```
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone;
    myDropzone = this;
    this.element.querySelector('button[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
    this.on('sendingmultiple', function() {});
    this.on('successmultiple', function(files, response) {});
    this.on('errormultiple', function(files, response) {});
  }
```

So I'm trying to figure how I can get all of these functions to work as they should or without the use of the `this` keyword and still self-reference?

> Edit

So with the Chrome extension: Javascript Errors Notifier. I was able to see the error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

I made a gist of the returned JavaScript here:

https://gist.github.com/justintech/d6d5bdb8468b79f60663

> Edit 2 - The form

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <form data-validate="true" class="form-horizontal form" id="new_item" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="/pbJ8IQK+ybIrjXFD7t2MIWzzFKsvmF7DA9oKSnNxouMk6i+jLNsboDZELHM5+w2qEnE0qzBEXyNFGl7HB85kQ==">
      <fieldset>
        </div>
          <main id="image-preview" class="dz-clickable">
          </main>
          <div class="submit-section">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Done" id="item-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any error at console ?

Comment: Do you have any info on the error? It could be that `myDropzone` has no method `processQueue` or there was no property `element` etc.

Comment: @Gal The error is something about `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. ` . If it helps I also made a gist of the file: https://gist.github.com/justintech/d6d5bdb8468b79f60663

Comment: @jh3y Thank you for commenting. I added details with the above comment that Gal is also looking at.

Comment: Do you have the submit button ready in your html at the time `init` runs?

Comment: well clearly your getting null from `this.element.querySelector('button[type=submit]')` use above `console.log(this)` to see what it contains.

Comment: @show-me-the-code Yeah, I posted the form above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this

```
document.querySelector('#item-submit')
```

instead of this

```
this.element.querySelector('button[type=submit]')
```

will fix the problem you are seeing. Will that work for you?

Comment: So `document` is what I could use to self reference a function?

Comment: No, but I don't see why you need to self-reference the function to identify a DOM element. My understanding is that you are trying to attach a click event to a submit button, which you can do by selecting the element in any way you like.

Comment: And your real problem here is that you have an unmatched `</div>` after the `<fieldset>`, which causes the DOM hierarchy to break, and the `querySelector` cannot find the children. If you change it to `<div>`, you will be able to use `this.element.querySelector('#item-submit')` also.

Comment: Oh damn, didn't know that mattered. So in the future I will correct my HTML also. Thanks.